# как указать путь к общей папке Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, share, sh

Добрый день Уважаемые,

Создал скрипт на linux и написал несколько команды:

```
cp -f smb://192.168.0.5/pyx/file.pyx
pkill python3
```

выполняю через терминал:

sh comm.sh

result:

```
cp: cannot stat 'smb://192.168.0.5/pyx/file.pyx': No such file or directory
```

а 2 команда выполняется без проблем.

Samba client работает норм, через проводник открываю этот путь открывается все файлы есть. smb://192.168.0.5/pyx/ - это путь к WINDOWS системе.

**Вопрос: В чем проблема и как исправить подскажите добрые люди? Заранее всем спасибо за отклики.**

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/smbget

Answer (score 5):

Доступ к smb ресурсу по пути smb:// возможен только через проводник. При этом проводник монтирует ресурс в каталоге /media. Во всех остальных случаях ресурс нужно смонтировать перед его использованием.

В вашем случае

```
mount -t cifs -o username=<user>,password=<pass> //192.168.0.5/pyx /mnt/pyx
```

каталог /mnt/pyx должен быть создан до операции монтирования.

Для отключения монтирования можно выполнить команду

```
unmount /mnt/pyx
```

**UPD:**

Копирование файлов с SMB ресурса без монтирования

```
smbclient -U <username> //192.168.0.5/pyx "<password>" <<EOF
get "file.pyx"
exit
EOF
```

Comment: а один раз смонтировал и все можно забыть или при перезагрузке опять надо будет?

Comment: При перезагрузке нужно монтировать снова. Или настроить соответствующую запись в fstab или более экзотичный вариант: настроить automount. Вот здесь более побробно https://oss-it.ru/157

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: В первом предложении чушь написал. Можно без монтирования файлы копировать.